# Customise mailboxes shortcuts

Tags: mail.app, shortcut

Is there a way to change the shortcuts to mailboxes?

Since I don't care usually about VIPs/drafts (see attached fig.), it would be more helpful to have rather *trash* and *archive*, for instance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortcuts correspond to the order in which they appear on the Favourites Bar, underneath the toolbar. If you add, remove or rearrange mailboxes there, the shortcuts will change accordingly.

If your Favourites Bar isn't currently visible, you can show it using the `View > Show Favourites Bar` menu.

http://www.cultofmac.com/202280/go-to-favorite-mailboxes-with-keyboard-shortcuts-os-x-tips/

Comment: great, thanks! I never realised I could actually move those objects - coming from linux, where this is usually not the case...